# How to fix in <module> Error for my neural network?

Tags: python, module, neural-network

I get the following error File "C:/Users/xx/Desktop/xxx/ost.py", line 213, in 
    main(), while trying to initiate training of neural network

This is for a final lab assignment about pictures classification

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

and the main function is

```
def main():
    with open('train.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)

    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]

    # x=feature_extraction_hog(x)

    D = x.shape[1]

    hidden_size = 55
    output_size = 36

    w1 = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1, size=(hidden_size, (D + 1)))
    w2 = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1, size=(output_size, (hidden_size + 1)))

    w1, w2 = fit(x, y, True, output_size, hidden_size, w1, w2, 0.2, 0.2)

    np.savetxt('weights1.txt', w1)
    np.savetxt('weights2.txt', w2)

    y_train_pred = predict(x, w1, w2)

    print(classification_error(y_train_pred, y))
```

Comment: Please include the complete traceback, that contains the error, the part you copied here doesn't tell you anything.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, the problem was with a line that received too many indexes! Thanks anyways